# Translation for "Control Panel" in a web interface context

Tags: choix-de-mot, informatique

What's the best translation for "Control Panel" in a web interface context? This would be the default page you arrive after logging in and managing an online account.

> Panneau de contrôle

or

> Tableau de bord

It's for the title of a website navigation element bringing you to the "back-end" where you can managed your account. This navigation element appears after logging in

Comment: [N'utilisez pas les blocs de code pour les citations.](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/nutilisez-pas-les-blocs-de-code-pour-les-citations-do-not-use-code-blocks-for) :-)

Answer (score 3):

“*Tableau de bord*” and “*Panneau de contrôle/configuration*” do not mean the same thing. “*Tableau de bord*” is only used to present an overview of a project, a profile, etc: you may not be able to configure anything through this.

The translation depends on the purpose of your Control Panel.

- Is that an overview? “*Tableau de bord*”.
- Is that made to (re)define parameters? As Shashimee wrote, “*Panneau de configuration*”, or “*Page d'administration*”.

Comment: It's for the title of a website navigation element bringing you to the "back-end" where you can managed your account. This navigation element appears after logging in.

Answer (score 2):

“*Tableau de bord*” is more appropriate and is the actual title in my company web apps. “*Panneau de contrôle*” is usually more about options and settings. For instance the Control Panel in Windows is called “*Panneau de configuration*” in French, which is similar.